# MySQL General Log Not Starting on 'Set Global'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up my MySQL general log so that it can be switched on and off by using

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'
```

I would like it off by default (i.e. on server startup) but then have the ability to toggle it as above, so that I don't have to keep restarting the server. When I attempt to switch general logging ON  as above, MySQL generates the following error:

```
Table 'mysql.general_log' doesn't exist
```

This is true - I have purposely not created this table as I would like logging to occur to file - NOT to tables. This suggests to me that that MySQL is trying to log the general queries to table even though the relevant global variables are set as below:

```
log_output = FILE
general_log = OFF
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql-general.log
```

The relevant part of the my.cnf is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
general-log = OFF
general-log-file = /var/log/mysql-general.log
```

I am using MySQL version 5.1.58 on a Linux server.

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: Andy check your variables using show variables and add into your question with log-output, general-log, general-log file name to understand it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table `mysql.general_log` does not exist, I assume you upgraded from a previous version of MySQL and need to run mysql_upgrade to create them.

**Backup all of your databases using `mysqldump` and do a filesystem backup of `/var/lib/mysql`**, then execute the following commands:

```
mysql_upgrade -p --force
```

followed by

```
service mysql restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

If the general_log table still does not exist after taking these steps, follow the steps in this post: [MySql - I dropped general_log table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247063/mysql-i-dropped-general-log-table) to manually create it.