# I dropped general_log table, how do I create it again?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

### Logging enabled

I enabled logging [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678310/471214):

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

All executed queries was logging to `mysql.general_log` table. It is fine.

### Attempt to clear the table

Then the table became large and I wanted to delete all records from the table. I executed:

```
DELETE FROM general_log
```

But this caused to an error that says I cannot lock log tables. So, I dropped the table after disabling logging:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
DROP TABLE general_log;
```

I hope that enabling logging again will create the table, but I couldn't enable it. When I execute this:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

It gives this error:

> Table 'mysql.general_log' doesn't exist

### Questions

1. How to create `mysql.general_log` again?
2. How to clear `mysql.general_log` safely and in a painless way?

Comment: +1 for not saying "My coworker executed `DROP TABLE`"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Recreate:

```
USE mysql;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log';
```

### Clear table:

```
TRUNCATE table mysql.general_log;
```

Answer (score 5):

For 1.:

```
USE mysql;
CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
    `event_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `user_host` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    `thread_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `server_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `command_type` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `argument` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
)
COMMENT='General log'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=CSV;
```

For 2.:

```
TRUNCATE mysql.general_log;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, only one answer can be accepted altough the answers almost all the same. I accepted first answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is the updated version, the 2012 answers do not work anymore:

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.general_log (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
```

Comment: The difference being ... the size of the `thread_id` column. You should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 5):

### MySQL 5.7.18

I have dropped the `mysql.general_log` table too, but the other answers did not help me.

Then, I noticed errors about the table structure cause it's a bit different on `MySQL 5.7.18`, so I have changed some field and now it works.

In case anybody needs it:

```
CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumblob
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, having first hand experience, this is what worked for me, if your table gets corrupted by any reason whatsoever, works  with MySQL 5.6.11

```
use mysql;
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';

DROP TABLE general_log;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,  -- Be careful with this one.
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
);

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';

select * from mysql.general_log
order by event_time desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreate table in MySQL 8.0.17:

```sql
use mysql;
CREATE TABLE general_log(
event_time timestamp(6) NOT NULL ,
user_host mediumtext NOT NULL,
thread_id bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
server_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
command_type varchar(64) NOT NULL,
argument mediumblob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log';
```