# DELETE old rows from Mysql General Log Table (MyISAM not CSV)

Tags: mysql, logging

I wanted to delete old rows from my `mysql.general_log` table but ran into this error:

```
#1556 - You can't use locks with log tables.
```

This is the query I ran:

```
DELETE FROM `general_log` WHERE `event_time` < "2014-01-25 14:05"
```

Comment: There are a couple of [bugs filed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30487) against this. It seems to be a persistent cosmetic error. Did your query actually work? If so, ignore the message.

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I try the accepted solution I get: #1017 - Can't find file: '.\XXX@002XXX\general_log.frm'  , any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure but are you using a table or a file for the error output? See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-destinations.html

Comment: I had to hunt around a bit there were  a couple of additional issues, the Rename table in techhero was failing due to permissions.  I also found that I had a very old general_log table, which was no longer working.  I updated it using : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247063/mysql-i-dropped-general-log-table  and everything works now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can rename the table, perform the cleaning as needed, then revert the table name again.

Example:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
RENAME TABLE general_log TO general_log_temp;
DELETE FROM `general_log_temp` WHERE `event_time` < DATE(NOW());
RENAME TABLE general_log_temp TO general_log;
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: The above worked for me but only after I turned-off logging as per the docs:

    `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';`

Comment: you may want to select the right db also ,start with `use mysql` then do what's in the answer